# Clickhouse SET command on a cluster?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse cluster.

It's great but I'm struggling to enable allow_experimental_geo_types on the cluster.

I can do it on a single cluster

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (p Polygon, id UInt64) ENGINE=MergeTree() ORDER BY (id);
```

But as soon as I try to do this on a cluster we get an error.

Answer (score 0):

put to all servers

```
$ cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/allow_experimental_geo_types.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
   <profiles>
       <default>
           <allow_experimental_geo_types>1</allow_experimental_geo_types>
       </default>
   </profiles>
</yandex>
```

no other way for on_cluster